# How to bind class fields to ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

I have a Windows Store App project.

I created a Items Page. It's all default and i want to bind my custom class to it's `GridView` so that the elements can be properly displayed.

The GridView's ItemTemplate is set to `Standard250x250ItemTemplate`. I would like to use that template and tell it how to display my custom elements. How can i do that? Do i have to create my own ItemTemplate? I would like to use the existing one.

Btw I'm setting `itemGridView.ItemsSource` to my collection. Is that the correct way of telling the `GridView` what to display?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your item template

here is an example i did it using Obout Ajax LIB

```
Grid SegmentsGrid = new Grid();
GridRuntimeTemplate AirlinesTemplate = new GridRuntimeTemplate();
AirlinesTemplate.ID = "AirlinesTemplate1";
AirlinesTemplate.ControlID = "AirlinesComboBox1";
AirlinesTemplate.Template = new Obout.Grid.RuntimeTemplate();
AirlinesTemplate.Template.CreateTemplate += new Obout.Grid.GridRuntimeTemplateEventHandler(CreateAirlinesTemplate);

GridRuntimeTemplate ClassesTemplate = new GridRuntimeTemplate();
ClassesTemplate.ID = "ClassesTemplate1";
ClassesTemplate.ControlID = "ClassesComboBox1";
ClassesTemplate.Template = new Obout.Grid.RuntimeTemplate();
ClassesTemplate.Template.CreateTemplate +=new Obout.Grid.GridRuntimeTemplateEventHandler(CreateClassesTemplate);  

SegmentsGrid.Templates.Add(ClassesTemplate);
SegmentsGrid.Templates.Add(AirlinesTemplate);

  public void CreateAirlinesTemplate(Object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRuntimeTemplateEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph1 = new PlaceHolder();
        e.Container.Controls.Add(ph1);


        AirlinesComboBox.ID = "AirlinesComboBox1";
        AirlinesComboBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        AirlinesComboBox.Height = Unit.Pixel(200);
        AirlinesComboBox.DataTextField = "Airline_Long_Name";
        AirlinesComboBox.DataValueField = "Airline_Long_Name";
        AirlinesComboBox.EmptyText = "Select Airline ...";
        AirlinesComboBox.EnableLoadOnDemand = true;
        AirlinesComboBox.LoadingItems += AirlinesComboBox1_LoadingItems;

        ph1.Controls.Add(AirlinesComboBox);
    }

 protected void AirlinesComboBox1_LoadingItems(object sender, ComboBoxLoadingItemsEventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting the countries
        DataTable data = GetAirlines(e.Text);

        // Looping through the items and adding them to the "Items" collection of the ComboBox
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            (sender as ComboBox).Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(data.Rows[i]["Airline_Long_Name"].ToString(), data.Rows[i]["Airline_Long_Name"].ToString()));
        }

        e.ItemsLoadedCount = data.Rows.Count;
        e.ItemsCount = data.Rows.Count;
    }


  protected void ClassesComboBox1_LoadingItems(object sender, ComboBoxLoadingItemsEventArgs e)
    {
        // Getting the countries
        DataTable data = GetClasses(e.Text);

        // Looping through the items and adding them to the "Items" collection of the ComboBox
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            (sender as ComboBox).Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem(data.Rows[i]["Class_Name"].ToString(), data.Rows[i]["Class_Name"].ToString()));
        }

        e.ItemsLoadedCount = data.Rows.Count;
        e.ItemsCount = data.Rows.Count;
    }

    public void CreateClassesTemplate(Object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRuntimeTemplateEventArgs e)
    {
        PlaceHolder ph1 = new PlaceHolder();
        e.Container.Controls.Add(ph1);


        ClassesComboBox.ID = "ClassesComboBox1";
        ClassesComboBox.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        ClassesComboBox.Height = Unit.Pixel(200);
        ClassesComboBox.DataTextField = "Class_Name";
        ClassesComboBox.DataValueField = "Class_Name";
        ClassesComboBox.EmptyText = "Select Flight Class ...";
        ClassesComboBox.EnableLoadOnDemand = true;
        ClassesComboBox.LoadingItems += ClassesComboBox1_LoadingItems;
        ph1.Controls.Add(ClassesComboBox);
    }
```